# Lagrangian multiplier

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics

Consumer's problem 
\begin{equation}
\max \sum_{t}\beta^{t}[c_{t}-1/2(1-x_{t})^{2}],
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ s.t. c_{t}+q_{t}b_{t+1} \leq (1-\tau_{t})(1-x_{t})+b_{t},
\end{equation}
where c=consumption, x=leisure(1-x=labor), $\tau$=labor income tax, 
b_{t+1}=the gov's bond, which is sold in period t at price q_{t}.
Time endowment is normalized to 1.

\begin{equation}
\ L=\sum_{t}\beta^{t}[c_{t}-1/2(1-x_{t})^{2}]+\lambda[c^{t}+q_{t}b_{t+1}-b_{t}-(1-\tau_{t})(1-x_{t})]
\end{equation}
First order conditions
\begin{equation}
w.r.t. c_{t}: \beta^{t}-\lambda=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
w.r.t. x_{t}: -\beta^{t}(1-x_{t})(-1)-\lambda(1-\tau_{t})(-1)=0 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
w.r.t. b_{t}: ?
\end{equation}

Comment: This seems trivial. What exactly is causing you trouble? Is it the $\sum$ sign?

Comment: Also $c^t$ seems to be a misspelled version of $c_t$.

Comment: Just take the derivative of $L$ w.r.t. $b_t$, but don't forget that in period $t-1$, $b_t$ shows up with a coefficient of $\lambda q_{t-1}$.

Comment: Two things  1. I think that signs inside the brackets after lambda should be reversed. 2. Although taking derivative with $b_t$ works, technically it should be with $b_(t+1)$, since this period’s bond is observed and next period’s bond is to be selected.